# How can I modify the knetworkmanager icon in my kde taskbar?

Tags: icons, appearance, kde4

I am using kubuntu 12.04 Precise 64 on my notebook.  Almost everything works fine.

I would like to modify the colors of the icon(s) used by knetworkmanager to indicate wifi online.

Right now, I am using the (default?) Oxygen theme.  What I want is to make the online icons some color other than gray - probably black, so the contrast is greater and they're easier for me to see (I use reading glasses.)

I found an old article on how to do this, but when I added the icons it mentioned, they were ignored.

Where are these icons stored?

Can I just edit them with something like gimp to change the colors, etc.?

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Tweaking plasma**

http://userbase.kde.org/Plasma/TweakingPlasma

**The Plasma Icons**

http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/Plasma/Theme

-> http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/Plasma/ThemeDetails

--> http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/Plasma/ThemeDetails#.22icons.22_folder

You need a svg /1/ capable image editor (Inkscape, Karbon).

[image]

The default plasma icons are: /usr/share/kde4/apps/desktoptheme/default/icons/

For a user:  ~/.kde/share/apps/desktoptheme/...

**A net article**

http://maketecheasier.com/use-custom-tray-icons-in-kde/2011/11/30

**Links**

1. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SVG

Comment: Thanks.  That's a lot to look at.  I'll get back when I have digested some of it.